# Fetching a single row of data from the database with a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having some issues with this.

I'm still new to mysqli and prepared statements.

I receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in ************** on line 191

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, news_title, news_body, news_poster FROM rr_news WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($news_id, $news_title, $news_body, $news_author); // this is line 191

$stmt->fetch();
```

http://prntscr.com/3kma1a - this is the contents of the entire database. as you can see, it is very small.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I fancy this is because you are using an old form of the MySQL driver and the `longtext` type. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I am using the `longtext` type. I'm not sure what you are talking about with the driver.

Comment: I changed the type from `longtext` to `blob` and it works! Thank you for your help.